# How to remove unwanted dots from strings in pandas column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I have a data that contains the column as following:

```
mouse.pad.v.1.2
key.board.1.0.c30
pen.color.4.32.r
```

I am removing digits by

```
df["parts"]= df["parts"].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Once the digits are removed the data looks like the following:

```
mouse.pad.v..
key.board...c
pen.color...r
```

what I want to do is to replace more than one dot from the column with just one dot. Ideal output should be

```
mouse.pad.v
key.board.c
pen.color.r
```

I tried using

```
df["parts"]= df["parts"].str.replace('..', '.')
```

But I am not sure how many dots will be combined together. Is there a way to automate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["parts"] = df["parts"].str.replace(r"\.*\d+", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         parts
0  mouse.pad.v
1  key.board.c
2  pen.color.r
```

---

Input dataframe:

```
               parts
0    mouse.pad.v.1.2
1  key.board.1.0.c30
2   pen.color.4.32.r
```